# Determine whether the full page or update panel is refreshing?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I'm manually triggering an update panel refresh using javascript (long story- but it has to be this way), but I still see a page flicker outside of the update panel, so I'm concerned that the whole page is getting refreshed rather than the update panel.  Any way I can determine this?  Perhaps some value in the code-behind on the postback?  Or some client side trick?  If the jQuery $(document).ready() event fires, does that mean the whole document is refreshing or just the update panel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If this is in a dev environment, the best way is to put a <%=DateTime.Now%> in your page outside of the update panel.  Since that will update each time the page is loaded, you'll have your hard proof.

Answer (score 1):

look and see if the browser's progress bar is loading in the status bar. That indicates a full page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

`ScriptManager.GetCurrent().IsInAsyncPostBack` will tell you if it's async or not. If javascript code in  `document.ready()` is running on the client, it is *probably* not an async postback. Any startup javascript that's outside an `UpdatePanel` would never run again on an async postback. However, if you register such a script from code that's part of an update panel, then it could still run.

Comment: "if you register such a script from code that's part of an update panel, then it could still run" - I tried attaching a listener to a DOM element using a script within an update panel, but it only runs once. The script manager seems to replace the DOM elements with each refresh, but not reload/rerun the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Page.IsCallback` to determine if the handler is being called as a result of an ajax call.